# Shell bash how to delete text between pattern not inclusive?

Tags: html, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to delete the text between `<pre><\pre>` html tags using:

```
sed -i '/<pre>/,/<\/pre>/d' file.html
```

But this deletes the `<pre></pre>` tags too. The are only one pre tag pair in the file.
How can I avoid to delete de pre tags?
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/sed+extract+string+between+two+patterns

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94616/removing-text-between-two-specific-strings

Comment: Try this

sed -i '/<pre>/,/<\/pre>/{//!d}' file.html

Comment: Would you please try: `sed -E ':l;N;$!bl;s#(<pre>).*(</pre>)#\1\2#' file.html`

Comment: @Sagii @tshiono @potong actually many solutions works but it depends very specific in the `<pre>` tags pattern, i had to insert a line break after `<pre>` in order to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<pre>/{p;:a;n;/<\/pre>/!ba};p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

If a line contains `<pre>`, print it and fetch the next line.

If that line does not contain `</pre>` loop back and repeat.

Otherwise print all other lines.